# how to use momentjs to show how many hours:min:sec ago

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have a date/time stamp `'2022-09-01T13:06:04.401650592Z'`. I want to display in a column the time elapsed since the time in `hh:mm:ss` but Im not sure if this is possible with moment.

I tried using `.fromNow()` but this does format correctly.

Ive also tried using `diff()` and `duration()` but this leaves me with negative values:

```
 const timeDiff = (t) => {
        const now = moment();
        const then = moment(t);

        const diff = then.diff(now)
        const dur = moment.duration(diff)

        return `${dur.hours()}:${dur.minutes()}:${dur.seconds()}`
    }
```

passing in `'2022-09-01T13:06:04.401650592Z'` to `timeDiff()` currently returns `0:-28:-57` which is not ideal. Is there a methos that gives you the timeSince now where I can call formatting on to get it into hours/min...etc?

Answer (score 0):

use `.asHours()` to get the hours length

```js
const timeDiff = (t) => {
  const now = moment();
  const then = moment(t);

  const diff = now.diff(then)
  const dur = moment.duration(diff)
  return `${parseInt(dur.asHours())}:${dur.minutes()}:${dur.seconds()}`
}

let diff = timeDiff('2022-09-01T13:06:04.401650592Z')
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```